# Custom fonts (woff2) doesn't work in Android making App with Visual Studio Comunity and Cordova

Tags: android, html, css, visual-studio-cordova, custom-font

Please help!!!

I have an App running with Visual Studio Comunity and Cordova, it works just perfect in the PC when I simulate it, but when I install it in my cell the fonts just doesn't work and it's killing me becouse I've tried every option I found in this page and it just doesn't work.

I have this code just in the index.html

```
    div>
      <style scoped>

        @font-face {
        font-family: 'Inknut Antiqua';
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 400;
        src: url(InknutAntiqua.woff2) format('woff2');
        }

      </style>
</div>

    <div>
        <h2  style="font-family: 'Inknut Antiqua'">Aqui va el Titulo</h2>
    </div>
```

This is the directory structure I have.

```
/Site
 -----/css
 -----/imgs
 -----index.html
 -----InknutAntiqua.woff2
```

P.D. I'm also using bootstrap `(<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">)` in case it could cause any trouble just like JQuery do to others, as I saw in other posts.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 4):

> when I install it in my cell the fonts just doesn't work.

WOFF2 is not supported in android 4.X webview. It is supported in 5.x-6.x. Please see [Can I use WOFF2 in Android](http://caniuse.com/#search=WOFF2).

But you can use WOFF. The difference is just the compression algorithm of the font. And WOFF does support Android 4.X.